# How to get the Profile name/Profile id of the Person who has liked the post in a fb page using facebook insights Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wanted to create a recommendation engine. I have a business page in facebook. I want to fetch the user names/user id and extra information of the persons who have liked the posts (like how google analytics gives for the website viewers). As far as i analysed, Facebook Graph API gives the count of the likes,comments etc.Could i get the user id's and timestamp of the person who have liked the posts along with the count

Comment: what for exactly? usually, data of users is not available unless each user specifically authorizes your app.

Comment: To know more insights about the user and to recommend right things to them

Comment: "recommend things to them" sounds like spam. did the user ever authorize you to do that in any way?

Comment: Of course yes... The permission will be obtained from the user